# Sound effects for multiple buttons on a page in WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, button, buttonclick, playsound

I have been scouring the internet, trying to find a way to play a short wav file on a button click. I want to put a total of 10 buttons on my homepage that would each play a different short sound.

I am building my site in WordPress. It seems like this should be easy but I don't know HTML or JavaScript. I suspect I could do this if I had those skills, and  if I knew how to insert code into my WordPress theme. I tried inserting 10 audio players onto the page, each playing their own sound, but it was a bulky, awkward way to handle this.

I found this code in a different post on this site, but I don't know where to put it or how to expand it to multiple buttons, each playing a different wav file.

```
var button = document.querySelector('button'),
    audio = null;

button.addEventListener('click', handler, false);

function handler() {
  audio = new Audio('https://www.gnu.org/music/FreeSWSong.ogg');
  audio.play();
}
<button>Play</button>
```

Your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation of your code

I will give a brief explanation to what the code you posted does, as well as point out some things that are worth noting.

```js
var button = document.querySelector('button')
```

[`document.querySelector('button')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) selects the **first** button in the entire document and assigns it to the `button` variable.

[`button.addEventListener('click', handler, false);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) adds a listener to `button` to execute `handler`. Here we run into a JavaScript peculiarity that is not obvious. We are referencing `handler` even though we haven't declared it yet. But fear not.

```
function handler() {
  audio = new Audio('https://www.gnu.org/music/FreeSWSong.ogg');
  audio.play();
}
```

Note that `handler()` is declared using `function`. This means that it will be what is called *hoisted* to the top of the scope. This can be loosely described as saying that the script will behave as if the following was written at the top of the script instead of where it is now.

```html
<button>Play</button>
```

What you posted was `JavaScript`. This is `HTML`. It won't work if you place them together like this. The `JavaScript` engine will come across this and say "I have no idea what this is", throw an error and refuse to do anything else afterwards.

To put `JavaScript` and `HTML` in the same place, you can put the `JavaScript` in a `<script>` tag in the HTML.

### A webpage that plays different sounds for different buttons

A reworked example would be something like this:

```html
<html>
   <audio id="beep" src="http://www.soundjay.com/button/beep-07.wav" autoplay="false" ></audio>
   <audio id="song" src="https://www.gnu.org/music/FreeSWSong.ogg" autoplay="false" ></audio>
   <button class="sound" id="beep">beep</button>
   <button class="sound" id="song">song</button>
   <script>
      // reference the audio elements
      var buttonSong = document.querySelector("audio#song")
      var buttonBeep = document.querySelector("audio#beep")
      
      // tell the buttons what to do when clicked
      document.querySelector("button.sound#beep")
              .addEventListener("click", () => buttonSong.play());
      document.querySelector("button.sound#song")
              .addEventListener("click", () => buttonBeep.play());
   </script>
</html>
```

This is a working webpage, you can copy past this into a text editor, save it with a `.html` extension and open it in your browser.

The first thing to note is that I've put the audio in `<audio>` tags. These are HTML tags and so the browser will start loading them when the webpage is loaded, instead of when the buttons are clicked, as in your question. This has a massive performance impact. Instead of downloading the song each time a user clicks a button, they are downloaded once, when they load the page.

In JavaScript, we then write code that for each of our buttons, when clicked, we play the sound.

This is the gist of how to play a sound when a button is clicked on a website. How to implement it in WordPress is a different question. You probably put it in a `footer.php` template for your theme.

### Some advice

What you ask isn't the most trivial to implement. Especially not on a WordPress site, which has it's own intricacies and complications. If you're new to web development, maybe try an easier problem first.

I realize you didn't ask for an opinion but think twice about the user experience of playing sounds when pressing buttons. It's not certain they will like it. I would recommend against playing an entire song, especially the *Free Software Song*.